# open graph debugger tool errors inferred property

Tags: facebook, blogger, facebook-opengraph

the past few days I've been working to get a facebook comment box installed on my blog that I've set up with open graph tags so that my blog can be liked as a facebook page. From what I can see on the page, all seems to be functioning normally, but when I run my blog address through the debugger, I get the following errors.

Here is the link to my site: [www.mommysnark.com](http://www.mommysnark.com)

And here are the errors that the debugging tool gives me:

A like button warning that should be fixed: 
og:title is missing. The og:title meta tag is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high clickthrough rate.

And finally, the open graph warnings that should be fixed:

Inferred Property:The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Inferred Property:The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Inferred Property:The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

It appears that everything is working, so can these errors just be ignored?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to correct all errors for best results. The properties `og:title` and `og:url` are especially important to your purposes. Here is the Open Graph stuff from my blog at [formlesspoet.blogspot.com](http://formlesspoet.blogspot.com/). You can use it for reference:

```xml
<!-- BEGIN FACEBOOK OPEN GRAPH -->
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;archive&quot;'>
    <meta expr:content='&quot;Posts from &quot; + data:blog.pageName + &quot; at Form and Formlessness&quot;' property='og:title'/>
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
 <b:if cond='data:blog.searchQuery'>
    <meta expr:content='&quot;Search results for “&quot; + data:blog.searchQuery + &quot;”&quot; + &quot; at Form and Formlessness&quot;' property='og:title'/>
 </b:if>
 <b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel'>
    <meta expr:content='&quot;Posts tagged under “&quot; + data:blog.searchLabel + &quot;”&quot; + &quot; at Form and Formlessness&quot;' property='og:title'/>
 </b:if>
 <b:if cond='data:blog.searchQuery == &quot;&quot;'>
  <b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel == &quot;&quot;'>
    <meta expr:content='&quot;Form and Formlessness&quot;' property='og:title'/>
  </b:if>
 </b:if>
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
    <meta expr:content='&quot;“&quot; + data:blog.pageName + &quot;”&quot; + &quot; at Form and Formlessness&quot;' property='og:title'/>
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
    <!--Static Page-->
</b:if>

<meta content='article' property='og:type'/>
<meta content='This blog follows an exploration of poetry by Zahhar, going as far back as 1995. Posts include his poetry and articles about poetry, prosody, and poetics.' property='og:description'/>

<meta expr:content='data:blog.url' property='og:url'/>   
<meta content='http://sphotos.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/538645_3357819035748_1577184006_2624573_712999292_n.jpg' property='og:image'/>
<meta content='1577184006' property='fb:admins'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.title' property='og:site_name'/>   
<!-- END FACEBOOK OPEN GRAPH -->
```

Note that the `og:title` property is set differently depending on what sort of page you're looking at. I'm trying to find a way to refine this further, but I'm still waiting on an answer. The `og:description` and `og:url` properties can be found near the bottom. Note that I'm using some Blogger specific stuff to get the title and URL of the current page for the `og:title` and `og:url` properties. You'll want to do the same. Presently the `og:description` property is static, but I plan to eventually find a way to make it more versatile. Still working on learning how. The URL used for the `og:image` property is actually linked to a photo in one of my Facebook albums.